Expand multiple columns in a when-then-otherwise expression
I want to write a polars when-then-otherwise expression with the following logic:
IF a1 and a2 are not null AND b1 and b2 are null 
THEN b1=a1, b2=a2 
ELSE keep values of b1 and b2

As an example I have this dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a1': [1,1,1], 
    'a2': [2,2,None], 
    'b1': [3,None,None], 
    'b2': [4,None,None]
    })

┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a1  ┆ a2   ┆ b1   ┆ b2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

I want this result
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a1  ┆ a2   ┆ b1   ┆ b2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
│ 1   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

I tried the following
df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('a1').is_not_null() &
                        pl.col('a2').is_not_null() &
                        pl.col('b1').is_null() &
                        pl.col('b2').is_null()
                       )\
                .then(pl.col('a1','a2'))\
                .otherwise(pl.col('b1','b2'))\
                .name.map(lambda x: {'a1':'b1','a2':'b2'}.get(x))
               )

but this raises an error
ComputeError: 'with_columns' failed
The reason: expanding more than one `col` is not allowed:


As of polars 0.20 there is a related issue: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13225

Update: You can also use a pl.struct.
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(
      pl.all_horizontal(pl.col("a1", "a2").is_not_null()),
      pl.all_horizontal(pl.col("b1", "b2").is_null())
   )
   .then(pl.struct(b1 = "a1", b2 = "a2"))
   .otherwise(pl.struct("b1", "b2"))
   .struct.field("b1", "b2") # or .struct.unnest()
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a1  ┆ a2   ┆ b1   ┆ b2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
│ 1   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘


It is somewhat verbose but another option could be to repeat the condition.
cond = pl.when(
   pl.all_horizontal(pl.col("a1", "a2").is_not_null()),
   pl.all_horizontal(pl.col("b1", "b2").is_null())
)

df.with_columns(
   b1 = cond.then('a1').otherwise('b1'),
   b2 = cond.then('a2').otherwise('b2')
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a1  ┆ a2   ┆ b1   ┆ b2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
│ 1   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

If we look at the query plan with LazyFrame.explain()
print(
    df.lazy().with_columns(
        b1 = cond.then('a1').otherwise('b1'),
        b2 = cond.then('a2').otherwise('b2')
    )
    .explain()
)

# WITH_COLUMNS:
# [.when(col("__POLARS_CSER_14873263077684770881")).then(col("a1")).otherwise(col("b1"))
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#  .when(col("__POLARS_CSER_14873263077684770881")).then(col("a2")).otherwise(col("b2"))
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

We can see that Polars identifies the pl.when() as a duplicated node, executes it once and caches the result into a temporary column.

You can't have multiple columns in the then/otherwise.
You either have to repeat the when/then/otherwise for each column of output or you can wrap them in a struct, drop the old columns, and unnest the struct.
(
    df
    .with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('a1').is_not_null() &
                        pl.col('a2').is_not_null() &
                        pl.col('b1').is_null() &
                        pl.col('b2').is_null()
                       )
                .then(pl.struct(b1='a1',b2='a2').alias('z'))
                .otherwise(pl.struct('b1','b2').alias('z'))
                )
    .drop('b1','b2')
    .unnest('z')
    )
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a1  ┆ a2   ┆ b1   ┆ b2   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
│ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
│ 1   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘


I would write it as such:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a1': [1, 1, 1], 
    'a2': [2, 2, None], 
    'b1': [3, None, None], 
    'b2': [4, None, None]
})

should_sub_b = (
    pl.col.a1.is_not_null() & pl.col.a2.is_not_null() &
    pl.col.b1.is_null() & pl.col.b2.is_null()
)

df = df.with_columns(
    b1=pl.when(should_sub_b).then(pl.col.a1).otherwise(pl.col.b1),
    b2=pl.when(should_sub_b).then(pl.col.a2).otherwise(pl.col.b2),
)

